# Locked and then accidentally orphaned folders. How do I get them back to visible and accessible?

Tags: windows-11, lock, files-folders

I have done a stupid thing and need help getting bailed out. I installed a file/folder lock app "EaseUS LockMyFile" (Windows 11 Home). I locked a couple of folders but wasn't happy with the app so I uninstalled it. But, I forgot to first unlock the folders I had previously locked before uninstalling.

Now the folders are no longer visible in my File Explorer tree. (But I can find files within these folders by searching for filenames! So much for lock security). Anyway, I need help "unlocking" the marooned folders and restoring them to be visible and accessible in the File Explorer view. From there, I will look for another locker app. Can anyone help with the unlocking process please?

Comment: Why not just reinstall it so the same passwords will then work to unlock/unhide? They don't state which encryption method they use, but claim 'military grade'… that's not going to be simple to crack.

Comment: So the program encrypts the file, by changing the file extension, this means if you cannot use the program to decrypt the files your files are lost to the encryption gods.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried that but folders were already locked and invisible :(

Comment: Well, you either persuade the original app to restore its setting/recover the password keys, or it's bye bye data [I'm assuming if you'd had a backup you wouldn't be asking the question… maybe next time you'll consider that any data in a single location is an accident waiting to happen. You just accelerated the accident.]